# Javascript Multiple conditions on an array filter without for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I've got an array as below

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, "foo", "", 4, "I am a string", ""]
```

I'm trying to filter all the populated strings into one array. I'm aware that this is possible with a for loop, however I'm looking for a neater way to do this.

My current method involves using two iterations of the filter,

```
arr = arr.filter(type => typeof(type) === 'string'); //find anything that's a string
return arr.filter(type => type!="") //filter array again to remove any empty values
```

however this seems a messy way to do things, is there anyway I can do this in one statement such as

```
return arr.filter(type => type!="" && typeof(type) === 'string') //this doesn't work
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Seems to work as far as I can tell...

Comment: It seems to work for me.

Comment: the last line *does* work. another option is `return arr.filter(type => typeof(type) === 'string').filter(type => type!="")`

Comment: Oh! It does work! I'm not sure what I was typing! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple really

```
arr = arr.filter(t => typeof t === 'string' && t != '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completenes, you could use the value itselft as [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (for example a string with some characters) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (for example an empty string) value and a check for the type.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, "foo", "", 4, "I am a string", ""],
    strings = array.filter(s => s && typeof s === 'string');

console.log(strings);
```